I got the key input to register into the game loop, but now it just doesn't register whenever I let go
The code works fine, jut whenever I let go of (in this case A) the character.x pos just keeps moving.
run = True
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit
            exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if keys[pygame.K_a]:
                player.moving_left = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            keys = pygame.key
            if keys == pygame.K_a:
                moving_left = False

I tried searching up different ways to get the keys registering but none worked the way I liked or they displayed errors.

In the KEYUP case, you assign moving_left = False, but I think you meant player.moving_left = False instead...

that still doesn't work.

for event in pygame.event.get():

    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit
        exit()

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            player.moving_left = True

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            player.moving_left = False


change key up detection to:
if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            keys = pygame.key.pressed()
            if keys[pygame.K_a]:
                player.moving_left = False


I tried that but it still wont stop moving the character.x pos, i think it may have to do with keys = pygame.key.GET_PRESSED() part.

yes, you are right. there are 3 errors in your code
